# Replace state using Object.assign

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For this React component with state `{ key: bool }`, why is the existing state key not omitted from the new state when a different option is clicked?

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/35003/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {};
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'foo')}>Foo</div>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'bar')}>Bar</div>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'baz')}>Baz</div>
        <div>{ 'Foo State: ' + this.state.foo }</div>
        <div>{ 'Bar State: ' + this.state.bar }</div>
        <div>{ 'Baz State: ' + this.state.baz }</div>
      </div>
    );
  },

  handleClick: function(id) {
    this.setState(Object.assign({}, { [id]: !this.state[id] } ));
  }

});
```

Here's what is happening:

1. click `Foo`: state becomes `{ foo: true }` (expected)
2. click `Foo`: state becomes `{ foo: false }` (expected)
3. click `Foo`: state becomes `{ foo: true }` (expected)
4. click `Bar`: state becomes `{ foo: true, bar: true }` (not expected)

I'm using `Object.assign` with the intention of wiping out any existing state and replacing it with the new key/bool pair.

Can someone explain why in Step 4, `{ foo: true }` remains in state?

How can I wipe out the existing state without having to know which option was previously active?

--

(Note: I added that last line after the original post, since it's not very helpful to know why `setState` behaves the way it does without knowing what to do about it. I'll accept an answer based on the original post. See my answer for a semi-clean way of replacing state with the non-deprecated API).

Comment: if you want to full replace state you can use `replaceState`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` itself is designed to merge the new state with the existing state (and update keys as necessary). You're never replacing the entire state with the new object.

It's also worth noting that there's no need to call `Object.assign` in this case. Your call to `setState` should just be:

```
this.setState({ [id]: !this.state[id] });
```

If you'd rather handle the merging yourself, you'd need to use [`replaceState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#replacestate) instead (which would give you the desired behavior):

```
this.replaceState(Object.assign({}, { [id]: !this.state[id] });
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` merges in keys, not overwrites the state completely.

Answer (score 0):

`replaceState` is deprecated (see [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#replacestate), [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3236), [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2843), [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/2805), and your console if you try to use it), and as Justin/Andy explained, `setState` will always merge, never replace.

The cleanest way I could think of to wipe out the existing state was to set an initial state of `{ active: {} }` and then use this one-liner to toggle or replace as necessary:

`this.setState({ active: (this.state.active[id]) ? {} : { [id]: true } });`